# Carregar configurações de ficheiro externo

Tags: angular, angular-5

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em Angular que se irá conectar a serviços externos. No entanto não tenho garantias que os caminhos dos serviços aos quais esta aplicação se liga se mantêm iguais e como tal o meu objetivo era ter um ficheiro de configurações externo com essas informações para não ter de recompilar e reimplantar a aplicação sempre que o endereço mude.

Com a Spring Framework em Java recorrendo a ficheiros `.properties` faria algo como

```java
public class RemoteService{
    @Value("${removeservice.address}")
    private String address;

    // Resto das coisas
}
```

Como poderia ter o mesmo comportamento no Angular?